# Force word-break on table cell

Tags: html, css

I'm using a div with display: table-cell on to vertically center this text, which can be multiple lines. I've stumbled upon that some words can get really long and this would make the element's layout to stretch even if it has a fixed width. Is there a way to break this word apart with pure css?

I've found that word-break: break-word works in Chrome 34. This is exactly what I want. If a word have room to break new line it should but if it's clipped - break that word up. But this doesn't work in Firefox and IE..

```
<style>
  .table {
    display: table;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }

  .table-cell {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
  }
</style>

<div class="table">
  <div class="table-cell">Loremipsumdolorsitamet</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3m6Q2/

Comment: try `word-wrap: break-word;`

Answer (score 4):

You should be using `word-break:break-all;`

```
.table-cell {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xzaQP/)**

Comment: Hmm, this works sort of how I want but then it breaks apart other words that can just break line instead. http://jsfiddle.net/xzaQP/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.table-cell{    word-wrap: break-word;
-ms-word-break: break-all;
word-break: break-all;
/* Non standard for webkit */
word-break: break-word;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
table-layout: fixed;}
```

Comment: Wow! Testing Firefox, formatting the single cell with "table-layout: fixed" like you suggest worked for me after adding "display: table; width: 100%;". Thanks for putting me on the right track. (The only solution I found for https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=587438 on the net btw.)